# Why does include work but not require when including file in Wordpress child theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, require

**Can someone please tell me why...**

I'm using a child-theme and I want to add a new php file test.php.

**I put this in functions.php**

```
//Gives correct file and path to the child-theme
echo get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . "/test.php"; 

//gives me a blank page (error).
require_once(  get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . "/test.php" ); 
//require(  get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . "/test.php" ); also throws an error
```

Why does the actual include give an error?

**WHILE**

```
//works perfectly
include(  get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . "/test.php" );
```

**works?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo), `get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')` returns the **stylesheet directory URL** of the active theme. This is not a file path...it's a URL.

`include` *doesn't* "work". Rather, it [throws a warning that it has not found the file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

`require`, on the other hand, throws a fatal error (which results in a blank page, because you don't have error reporting on).

The proper way of including this file would be to use something like:

```
require_once('test.php');
```

This assumes that *test.php* exists in the same directory as *functions.php*.

You can also use [`get_stylesheet_directory()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory) to retrieve stylesheet directory **path** for the current theme/child theme.

```
require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/test.php' );
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation! :-) I didn't really want to include test.php (I think you figured that out), I wanted to include recaptchalib.php but a require_once( 'recaptchalib.php' ) does not work and it gives me fatal error.- BUt require_once( 'test.php' ) works flawlessly! :-)

Comment: I figured it out and it was an issue with a current recaptcha plugin I tested before. When I deactivated it, it worked perfectly to include recaptchalib.php as expected.